# How can I use multiple combo boxes with one datasource in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

When I try to use the same list with multiple combo boxes, the selection is shared with all the combo boxes.

I want the combo box to treat the datasource as their own and selection should not be shared.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveLanguages}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

ActiveLanguages is a ObservableCollection and is a single instance object for the application.

This Combo Box is on a template, and the selection repeats itself on all the instance of the templates.

Comment: Are you able to post your xaml to see how you have declared the comboBoxes? I think you would need to specifically bind SelectedItem to the same property in your DataConext to observe that behaviour...

Comment: * that should have been DataContext, obviously ;)

Comment: It doesn't make sense that Thomas solution didn't worked. Can you elaborate with the full code and how you test/see that all the comboboxes share selection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property to false

Answer (score 2):

making a copy can eat a lot of memory depending on the size of the list.

A much better way is to use a BindingSource.

each UI object sets its datasource to a new copy of a BindingSource.

The BindingSources all set their .datasource = the same instance of whatever list you are trying to bind to.